# MySQL Server Startup error about update PID file

Tags: mysql

ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/localhost.localdomain.pid).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the pid file,which by default is located at MySQL's data directory unless specified elsewhere.Make sure no instance of MySQL server is currently running :

```
ps -ef |grep -i mysqld
```

Perform a shut down if there is a running instance:

```
mysqladmin shutdown -uroot -p
```

Start again.